# When are notarized macOS apps required?

Tags: xcode10, macos-mojave, osx-gatekeeper

In an upcoming release of macOS, Gatekeeper will require Developer ID signed software to be notarized by Apple.

Anyone know what macOS release it could be?

Answer (score 0):

Nobody knows for sure, but judging by how Apple does things, I'd guess they might require it in the next major release of macOS (10.15). However, that can be significantly delayed if developers and users start complaining that the notarization process introduced unexpected side effects or bugs or even security holes. In any case, I wouldn't count on it and you'd better be ready for macOS 10.15.